# Get last retweets/favorites using Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to get the last tweets from the user that have been retweeted/favorited but I want 1 entry for every retweets/favourites and order by the time of the retweet/favorite, not by the time the user tweeted that status. I can't find how to do it. Is it possible?

EDIT 1:

1. I send tweet T1, T2 and T3
2. User A retweets T2 and T3.
3. User B retweets T1 than T2.

I'm able to obtain a list of my tweets that have been retweeted, but I obtain retT3* retT2 retT1, only one entry per tweet and in the order from the newest tweets to the older.

What I want is a list like this:

1. retT2 -> The last tweet that has been retweeted
2. retT1
3. retT3
4. retT2 -> The first tweet that has been retweeted

*retTX means retweet of TX

Comment: Difficult to understand. `get the last tweets from the user that have been retweeted/favorited`

Comment: I edited my qyestion, hope it's clear now

Comment: Comparing timestamps can help?

Comment: Maybe, but I can't check every tweets of a user...for me would be checking 3000 tweets every time...

Comment: If you keep it in a database in sorted order can help!

Comment: Yes but I hope there's another way :/